# How to correspond numbers in the array to English alphabets?

Tags: arrays, c, string

I am learning about arrays and data types in C. My question is that how can I compute the sum of the chars of a string. The value of chars in POINTS array for example the value of A(or a) is 1 and B(or b) is 3 etc. Now my question is that how can tell my program that A is 1 because by default it is working with the asci table. I will be happy for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
/////////////// A  B  C  D . . .
int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{

    int score = compute_sum(Amazing!);
    //it must calculates 1 + 1 + 1 + 10 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 0
}

int compute_sum(string word)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<strlen(word);i++)
    {
        //todo
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: `'A' - 'A' + 1 = 1`, `'B' - 'A' + 1 = 2`, etc..

Comment: Assuming ASCII where all letters are encoded contiguously, you can subtract the characters `'A'` from a character to get its "value". Like `'A' - 'A` == 0`, and `'C' - 'A' == 2`, etc.). Once you have it's zero-based value you can use it as an index into your array.

Comment: You have an exclamation mark `!` after `Amazing`. Is that character also supposed to have a value?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel His example shows that the value should be `0`.

Comment: However to be fully portable I recommend you create a lookup-table like `char characters[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";`. Then you find the letter in the array, and its position will then be the index into the `POINTS` array.

Comment: What is type `string`? From context it appears to be a typedef for `char*`, but it would be clearer if you provided the exact definition. Also, you may be missing double quotes around `Amazing!`. Otherwise, your question is correctly written, focused and on-topic so, well done for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASCII and all character encodings derived from it (including Unicode) the letters in the Latin alphabet are all contiguous. So you can subtract the encoding of `A` or `a` from a letter to get its corresponding index.

```
int compute_sum(string word)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0 ; i<strlen(word);i++)
    {
        if (isupper(word[i])) {
            total += POINTS[word[i] - 'A'];
        } else if (islower(word[i])) {
            total += POINTS[word[i] - 'a'];
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: If the [locale](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale) is changed, then the behavior of `isupper` and `islower` may be changed to return true for other characters too, and the above code may access the `POINTS` array out of bounds.

Comment: Nitpick: If `word[i]` is negative, then, according to the ISO C standard, passing that negative value to `isupper` or `islower` will result in undefined behavior (unless that value happens to equal `EOF`). Therefore, casting the value to `unsigned char` would be safer. However, most platforms define the behavior for negative values, so it probably isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking I would probably do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

static const int points[UINT8_MAX + 1] = {
    ['a'] = 1,
    ['b'] = 3,
    ['c'] = 3,
    ['d'] = 2,
    ['e'] = 1,
    ['f'] = 4,
    ['g'] = 2,
    ['h'] = 4,
    ['i'] = 1,
    ['j'] = 8,
    ['k'] = 5,
    ['l'] = 1,
    ['m'] = 3,
    ['n'] = 1,
    ['o'] = 1,
    ['p'] = 3,
    ['q'] = 10,
    ['r'] = 1,
    ['s'] = 1,
    ['t'] = 1,
    ['u'] = 1,
    ['v'] = 4,
    ['w'] = 4,
    ['x'] = 8,
    ['y'] = 4,
    ['z'] = 10,
};

static int compute_sum(const char *word)
{
    const unsigned char *c;
    int sum = 0;

    for (c = (const unsigned char *) word; *c; c++)
        sum += points[(int) *c];

    return sum;
}

int main(void)
{
    int score;

    score = compute_sum("Amazing!");

    printf("Score: %d\n", score);
}
```

Rationale: more readable, less error prone, no arithmetic needed, less chance of UB.

Comment: and you have used pointers in your for loop, am I right?

Comment: @Aylin: The default [linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) of a function and a global variable is external. In this case, the keyword `static` changes the linkage to internal, so that the identifiers (name of the variables or functions) are not visible to other translation units (i.e. to other `.c` files).

Comment: @Aylin: Yes, a pointer was used to iterate through every character of the string.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel You are correct. I noted the problem once I posted my code. I should have used an `unsigned char *`, which I thought of when using `UINT8_MAX` but I failed to use the correct type for `c`. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: For consistency, use `UINT8_MAX, uint8_t` or `UCHAR_MAX, unsigned char`.  Might want  to make  case insensitive too.  Cast in `points[(int) *c]` not needed.